# linking table numbers between power point and excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I am trying to create a presentation file which will contain many tables. These tables though might change. So, I would like to know if there is there a way to link the numbers of a table from an excel file, with the numbers of a table in a powerpoint slide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy.

Steps:

1. **Create** the table in Excel
2. **Copy** the table in Excel
3. **Prepare** the slide in PowerPoint
4. **Paste Special** the Table on Your PowerPoint slide, using Paste Link
5. **Resize** and position the table object

And it's done!

---

**Example:**

Here's an example image of Paste Special and Paste Link options:

[image: paste_link]

---

**Hints:**

1. If you update the Excel spreadsheet data, when the PowerPoint file is opened, the new data will be retrieved and displayed. *(The system mays asks you to Update the linked data. Always update it with the latest information)*
2. If you move the Excel file, the link will not be able to update as it won’t be able to find the file in the original location. If this happens, just fix the spreadsheet link location.
3. If you want to edit the data in Excel, you can double click on the table object on the PowerPoint slide and the Excel spreadsheet will open.
4. If you want to prevent others from changing the data in the Excel spreadsheet, make the Excel file a read-only file. *(This will allow them to see the data in Excel when double clicking on the inserted table, but they won’t be able to save any changes to the file)*

Comment: This does not work for tables. (At least for me). I get half of the table pasted as image

Comment: "Table" in Excel has a special meaning. Don't create a table in Excel, just put the data into a worksheet and format it to taste, then copy/paste into PPT as described.